# Not able to get id of radiobutton via getCheckedRadioButtonId()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a custom dialog box which gives radio buttons to select from n then diplay text of radio button in the textfield. This is what i tried..

My Layout for dialog box is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rg_carType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_hatchD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hatchback(Diesel)" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_hatchP"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hatchback(Petrol)" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_sedanD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sedan(Diesel)" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_sedanP"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sedan(Petrol)" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_suv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SUV" />
</RadioGroup>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_carType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rg_carType"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_confirmCar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rg_carType"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_2"
    android:text="Confirm"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

And the function for custom dialog box is

```
private void diplayCartype() {
final Dialog dialog_car = new Dialog(FinalActivity.this);
final RadioButton rb_select;
RadioGroup rg_carType;
ImageView iv_carType;
Button btn_confirmCar;
String sCar="?";
dialog_car.setTitle("Select Car Type");

dialog_car.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_cartype);

iv_carType=(ImageView)dialog_car.findViewById(R.id.iv_carType);
btn_confirmCar=(Button)dialog_car.findViewById(R.id.btn_confirmCar);
rg_carType=(RadioGroup)dialog_car.findViewById(R.id.rg_carType);

int selected=rg_carType.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
rb_select=(RadioButton)dialog_car.findViewById(selected);

switch(selected)
{
    case R.id.rb_hatchD:
        iv_carType.setImageResource(R.drawable.hatch_d);
        sCar=rb_select.getText().toString();
        break;
    case R.id.rb_hatchP:
        iv_carType.setImageResource(R.drawable.hatch_p);
        sCar=rb_select.getText().toString();
        break;
    case R.id.rb_sedanD:
        iv_carType.setImageResource(R.drawable.sedan_d);
        sCar=rb_select.getText().toString();
        break;
    case R.id.rb_sedanP:
        iv_carType.setImageResource(R.drawable.sedan_p);
        sCar=rb_select.getText().toString();
        break;
    case R.id.rb_suv:
        iv_carType.setImageResource(R.drawable.suv);
        sCar=rb_select.getText().toString();
        break;
    default:
        iv_carType.setImageResource(R.drawable.suv);
        sCar="default";
}
final String finalSCar = sCar;
btn_confirmCar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        tv_carType.setText(finalSCar);
        dialog_car.dismiss();
    }
});
dialog_car.show();
}
```

The problem is that the switch case executes only default condition, that means its not getting id to check. Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: where / when is `diplayCartype` being called?

Comment: displayCartype is called on the click of a linear layout which contains the textfield in which the text is to be displayed

Comment: why dont you use `RadioGroup#setOnCheckedChangeListener`?

Answer (score 0):

About `getCheckedRadioButtonId()`

> Returns the identifier of the selected radio button in this group.
>   Upon empty selection, the returned value is -1.

There is no selected `RadioButton` at the moment when you are trying to check for selected one.

```
dialog_car.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_cartype);

// at this point you have newly created view hierarchy and
// RadioGroup has no selected items

iv_carType=(ImageView)dialog_car.findViewById(R.id.iv_carType);
btn_confirmCar=(Button)dialog_car.findViewById(R.id.btn_confirmCar);
rg_carType=(RadioGroup)dialog_car.findViewById(R.id.rg_carType);

// still has no selected items, next call returns -1 as well
int selected=rg_carType.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

You should use `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` from handler of some extra button (e.g. "OK") to be sure that user has seen your radio buttons and has enough time to select something.

Comment: i m able to see the dialog box when executed...and i am selecting the radioButton..But still the switch case goes to default

Comment: @Let'sLearnit You are trying to get selection from a just created view, that has no selected item yet. See my edit.

Comment: yes i m getting ur point...if there is no selected items.. i can put a default checked item...but that will just pick the default item only...how can i select the item from here...

Comment: @Let'sLearnit You should setup dialog UI and instead of picking selected one you should just set `OnClickListener` for your `btn_confirmCar` (as you have done already). And then you'll pick selection from that click listener, i.e. not when you've just created views but when user has pressed that button (as confirmation of the fact that car type was selected)

Answer (score 0):

this code work for me

```
public class RadioButtonFragment extends DialogFragment {
    String singleitem;
    private int witch;
    private MySharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = new MySharedPreferences();
    private String[] item = {"Naskh asiatype", "Fajer noori Nastaleeq", "Pak nastaleeq (default)"};

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       witch= mySharedPreferences.loadIntPrefs(Constants.RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX_KEY,2,getActivity());

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        witch= mySharedPreferences.loadIntPrefs(Constants.RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX_KEY,2,getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("please selet any fount").setSingleChoiceItems(item, witch, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                singleitem= item[which];
                mySharedPreferences.saveStringPrefs(Constants.FONT_KEY,singleitem,getActivity());
                mySharedPreferences.saveintPrefs(Constants.RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX_KEY,which,getActivity());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Font is selected"+which,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

and call to build this fragment

```
RadioButtonFragment radioButtonFragment = new RadioButtonFragment();
        radioButtonFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), RadioButtonFragment_TAG);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need read the value at the right time (button click). Do this:

```
btn_confirmCar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View view) {
        rg_carType=(RadioGroup)dialog_car.findViewById(R.id.rg_carType);

        int selected=rg_carType.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        rb_select=(RadioButton)dialog_car.findViewById(selected);

        switch(selected)
        { 
            case R.id.rb_hatchD:
                iv_carType.setImageResource(R.drawable.hatch_d);
                break; 
            case R.id.rb_hatchP:
                iv_carType.setImageResource(R.drawable.hatch_p);
                break; 
            case R.id.rb_sedanD:
                iv_carType.setImageResource(R.drawable.sedan_d);
                break; 
            case R.id.rb_sedanP:
                iv_carType.setImageResource(R.drawable.sedan_p);
                break; 
            case R.id.rb_suv:
                iv_carType.setImageResource(R.drawable.suv);
                break; 
            default: 
                iv_carType.setImageResource(R.drawable.suv);
                sCar="default";
        }

        if (!sCar.equals("default"))
            sCar = rb_select.getText().toString();

        tv_carType.setText(sCar);
        dialog_car.dismiss();
    } 
}); 

dialog_car.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use an **interface (Listener)** for listening to **User Inputs**. For example you can use **RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener** and then place your **switch** statement in it.

```
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
             switch(checkedId){
                  case R.id.radioButtonId: 
                       // Your Code Here
                       break;                     
                  ---
             }
        }
    });
```

Your current code would statically pick the default values of initially assigned states. Above enhancements would help you handle user inputs dynamically.